# Scale and translate text in 2D with OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, 2d

I am trying to draw text in UI elements with OpenGL but i fail in computing scale
and translation values for different font sizes correctly, such that a text would
fit nicely into a designated area.
This is my first attempt in doing such a thing and it seemed to work until i
noticed that with increasing font size the text will not fit into the calculated area anymore. I am not allowed to attach an image for a visual impression of what i mean, which is very sad.

First i thought this would be caused by rounding the scaled font width in order
to calculate the width that a frame needs but was unable to verify this.
After much trial and error i am not even sure anymore if it's the text that
gets projected incorrectly, or the frames i am trying to fit the text into.

Please have a look and help me find the error, here's an overview of what i do:

I construct a UI element by passing a certain font size in pixels.
For a frame ( e.g. input box ) that should hold at most n characters
the computation would look like this:

```
- Get the width (in pixels) of a single character:
    x_advance and line_height are given by the fonts glyph description.
    Since i use mono spaced fonts i treat the x_advance as character width.

    font_oo_aspect      = 1 / ( x_advance / line_height )
    font_width          = roundf( font_size / font_oo_aspect )

- Computing the actual frame dimension + some margin:

    frame_height        = font_size + 2 * vertical pad
    frame_width         = n * font_width + 2 * horizontal_pad

    The x and y location in pixels of the frames top left corner
    are set to be relative to its parents top left corner.
```

When rendering UI elements first all frames are drawn and secondly the text.

```
- Computing scale and translation for a frame:
    ortho_scale_x       = 2 / window_width
    ortho_scale_y       = -2 / window_height
    wo2                 = frame_width * 0.5
    ho2                 = frame_height * 0.5
    dx                  = parent_x + location_x + wo2
    dy                  = parent_y + location_y + ho2

    scale_x             = ortho_scale_x * wo2
    scale_y             = ortho_scale_y * ho2
    translation_x       = dx / wo2
    translation_y       = dy / how

- Computing scale and translation for a text:

    view_aspect         = window_width / window_height
    font_scale          = line_height / ( view_aspect * font_size )

    scale_x             = ortho_scale_x * font_scale
    scale_y             = -ortho_scale_y * font_scale
    translation_x       = frame_location_x / font_scale
    translation_y       = -frame_location_y / font_scale
```

The respective scale and translation values are sent to the shader.
Here's the vertex shader code which is the same for frames and text:

```
    #version 130
    in vec2 vertex;
    in vec2 uv;
    uniform vec2 scale;
    uniform vec3 translation;
    out vec2 coords;
    void main( void ) {
        gl_Position = vec4(
            ( translation.x + vertex.x ) * scale.x - 1.0,
            ( translation.y + vertex.y ) * scale.y + 1.0,
            translation.z, 1.0 );
        coords = uv;
    }
```

I hope i provided everything relevant, if not please let me know.
Regards and thanks,
Alfred

Follows the render function for frames and text:

```
    // The buffer object data that frames use looks like this:
    float quad_data[ ] = { // x, y, u, v
         1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   // top left
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f    // bottom left
    };

    // Each text element is rendered as an individual vertex array object.            
    void render_frame_batches( void ) {
        int i, j;
        float f_font_size = 12; // 28;
        const float h = core.settings.height;
        const float sx = core.perspective.ortho_scale_x;
        const float sy = core.perspective.ortho_scale_y;
        const float view_aspect = core.perspective.view_aspect;
        float dx, dy, layer, wo2, ho2;

        Ui_Frame_Renderer *frame_renderer = &core.renderer.queue[ 0 ];
        Ui_Render_Batch_Frame *batch = frame_renderer->batch;
        Ui_Render_Target_Frame *target;
        Ui_Shader *p = &core.programs[ PROGRAM_FRAME ];
        const s16 *uni_loc = p->uniform_locations;

        glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
        glUseProgram( p->program_id );
        glUniform1i( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_TEXTURE0 ], 0 );
        glBindVertexArray( core.shape_vao[ SHAPE_QUAD ].vao );
        glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, core.shape_vao[ SHAPE_QUAD ].ind );

        for( i = 0; i < RENDER_BATCH_FRAME_MAX; i++ ) {
            layer = ( float ) batch->layer;

            for( j = 0; j < batch->frame_count; j++ ) {
                target = &frame_renderer->target[ batch->queue_index + j ];
                wo2 = ( float ) target->frame_width * 0.5f;
                ho2 = ( float ) target->frame_height * 0.5f;
                dx = ( float ) target->tx + wo2;
                dy = ( float ) target->ty + ho2;

                if( j > 0 ) {
                    dx += ( float ) batch->parent_x;
                    dy += ( float ) batch->parent_y;
                }
                glUniform2f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_SCALE ], sx * wo2, sy * ho2 );
                glUniform3f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_TRANSLATION ], dx / wo2, dy / ho2, layer );
                glUniform2f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_LOCATION ], dx, h - dy );

                s32 ib, ob;

                if( target->texture ) {  // slider gradients
                    ib = ob = 0;
                    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, core.dynamic_textures[ target->texture ] );
                } else {
                    ib = wo2 - target->detail.frame.inner_border;
                    ob = ho2 - target->detail.frame.outer_border;
                    glUniform4fv( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_COLOR_BG ],
                        1, ( float * ) &core.colors[ target->bg ] );
                    glUniform4fv( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_COLOR_FG ],
                        1, ( float * ) &core.colors[ target->fg ] );
                }
                glUniform1i( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_INNER ], ib );
                glUniform1i( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_OUTER ], ob );
                glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES,
                    core.shape_vao[ SHAPE_QUAD ].len, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );

                if( target->texture ) {
                    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0 );
                }
            }
            batch++;
        }
        frame_renderer++;
        batch = frame_renderer->batch;
        p = &core.programs[ PROGRAM_FONT ];
        uni_loc = p->uniform_locations;
        Ui_Font *f = &fonts[ FONT_MENU ];
        float font_scale = f->line_height / ( view_aspect * f_font_size );
        float ri, ro;
        font_stroke_radii( f_font_size, f->line_height, view_aspect, &ri, &ro );

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, f->tex_id );
        glUseProgram( p->program_id );
        glUniform1i( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_TEXTURE0 ], 0 );
        glUniform1i( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_FLAGS ], 1 );
        glUniform1f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_INNER ], ri );
        glUniform1f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_OUTER ], ro );

        for( i = 0; i < RENDER_BATCH_FRAME_MAX; i++ ) {
            layer = ( float ) batch->layer;

            for( j = 0; j < batch->frame_count; j++ ) {
                target = &frame_renderer->target[ batch->queue_index + j ];
                dx = ( float )( target->tx + batch->parent_x );
                dy = ( float )( target->ty + batch->parent_y );

                glUniform2f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_SCALE ],
                    sx / font_scale, -sy / font_scale );
                glUniform3f( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_TRANSLATION ],
                    dx * font_scale, -dy * font_scale, layer  );
                glUniform4fv( ( s32 ) uni_loc[ LOC_U_COLOR_FG ], 1,
                    ( float * ) &core.colors[ target->fg ] );

                Ui_Text *ui_text = &core.text_vao[ STATIC_STRING_MAX + target->detail.text.id ];
                Ui_Vao *obj = &ui_text->vao;
                glBindVertexArray( obj->vao );
                glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj->ind );
                glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, obj->len, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
                glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
                glBindVertexArray( 0 );
            }
            batch++;
        }
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
        glUseProgram( 0 );
    }
```

Comment: Text and fonts is a complex topic. For the starter read this: https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step2.html

Comment: Yes, thats why i  chose mono spaced fonts to begin with to avoid all those kerning issues. And i don't use any font library instead i create a texture atlas of signed distance fields with hiero. The tutorial you mention seems very thorough and i will study it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation for the font scale should look like this:

```
font_scale = line_height / font_size
```

Before that i had multiplied the font size with the aspect ratio, which i guess makes no sense as i later divide the two orthographic scale values by the font scale and those already got the width and height "baked" into them. Sorry i can't give a mathematical explanation, it just seems to work nicely with that little change.